# Grails - JavaScript Resource Module - onLoad

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a grails resource module set up:

```
modules {
    myModule {
        resources url:'js/application.js'
        resources url:'js/helper.js'
    }
}
```

And I can load this onto my GSP page using `<r:require ... />`.

**Problem**:

I want some JS code to fire when this script has loaded. Is there anyway to do this?

Even if I could do it via JS (script.onLoad) that would be ok, I'm just not sure how to generate a link to the module using grails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include your module in your GSP page as:

```
<r:require modules="myModule" />
```

and you can fire any java script function in you js files on page load.

in case your module will not get loaded on the GSP, try adding disposition, i.e.

```
modules {
    myModule {
        resources url:'js/application.js', disposition: 'head'
        resources url:'js/helper.js', disposition: 'head'
    }
}
```

I think better way to include your resources on the view pages, is through layout, I used to do it like, adding all the resources on the layout page, ex. layout->main.gsp

add all the required resources on this page as:

```
<r:require
    modules="myModule" />

<g:layoutHead />
<r:layoutResources />
```

then on all the GSP pages in the application you can apply this layout, i.e.

```
<g:applyLayout name="main"/>
```

and to call any java script code(on the included js files) on script load, I think you should associate it with the onload event on the gsp page.

Comment: Sweet, thanks. I went with disposition 'defer' in the end but got it to work.